# stack level too deep ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

A true stack overflow... this is my first go at emailing from an app.

From the form:

```
<%= form_tag request_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: 'Find...', class: 'ui-corner-all' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send request", class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

to the controller:

```
def request
  user_email = params[:email]
  UserMailer.request(user_email).deliver
  #flash[:notice] = "We'll let #{@user[:name]} know!"
end
```

via the mailer:

```
def request(email)
  @url = "http://mysite.herokuapp.com/"

  mail to:          email,
       subject:     "#{first_name(current_user)} would like to say hi!"
end
```

I get this in my console:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70

  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (31.2ms)
```

Google has failed me, so hopefully someone here has a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is a keyword in Rails.  That's a big no no.  I changed it in all locations to `request_pal` and all is well.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? I don't really get what you are trying to explain!

Comment: my bad.  was answering my own question.  `request` is a keyword of some sort.  using it is a 'no no.'  i changed all instances of that word to `request_pal` and i was able to kill the infinite loop.

Comment: You should edit these explanations in your answer! In order to help future user looking at that question!

Comment: well, when able (i have about 20 more hours, it would seem), i'll accept this as an answer.  I don't want to modify the original, so if the same issue does arise, it is shown as is.  cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using delayed_job in your project ?

I had a similar issue few days back with delayed_job.
[This](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349) helped me back then.

Comment: no... i changed some stuff around.  `request` is a keyword of some sort.  i changed it, and it worked =)